# Selenium wire throwing invalid server specification error for authenticated proxy

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver, seleniumwire

The following code throws

```
from proxy import getProxy
from seleniumwire import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

username , password , ip , port = getProxy()

options = {
    'proxy': 
        {
            'http': f"http://{username}:{password}@{ip}:{port}",
            'https': f"https://{username}:{password}@{ip}:{port}",
            'no_proxy': 'localhost,127.0.0.1'
        }
}

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe', seleniumwire_options=options)

driver.get('http://whatismyipaddress.com')

time.sleep(8)

driver.quit()
```

this error:
[image: error output]

I am trying to use an authenticated proxy by using selenium wire but i get an invalid server specification error